# How to compile Apach AVRO IDL into java?

Tags: java, python, avro

I have an Apache AVRO IDL that defines a protocol that I would like to use between a java client and a server written in Python.

```
@namespace("myproto.proto")

protocol myproto 
{

  enum Status
  {
    STATUS_OK,
    STATUS_ERROR
  }

  record GameList
  {
    array<string> games;
  }

  void somefunc(int arg);
}
```

For Python, I use this:

```
AVROTOOLS=$(TOOLS_PATH)/avro-tools-1.7.4.jar
java -jar $(AVROTOOLS) idl fairunfair.avdl fairunfair.avpr
```

How can I compile the IDL into Java? Without using maven, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generate a JSON schema from your IDL with avro-tools:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.4.jar idl /path/to/idl
```

Then just compile the schema into Java as usual:

```
java -jar avro-tools-1.7.4.jar compile schema /path/to/schema .
```

I don't think there is any way to compile directly to Java from IDL. The avro-tools help menu reveals no such option.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I need to do "compile protocol" instead. Strange that an IDL file cannot simply describe a schema, rather than a protocol.